# How can I print a list of attributes from DynamoDB table in Lex Bot?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex

I created a lex bot and a dynamodb table. The table has three columns: Carname (Column A), Color (Column B) and Price (Column C). If the user types in 'Carname', I want the bot to suggest the available colors from the table to the user so that the user can select the color and will get the price for the chosen carname and color.

How can I make the bot show the available colors for the chosen 'Carname'?

For example, the user says 'Impala'. In the DynamoDB table, there are two entries for 'Impala': In one entry, you will find 'blue' as column B, in the second entry, you find 'black' as column B.

The bot should draw the available colors from column B and propose them to the user. In the next step of the dialog, the user selects a color. After this, the bot answers with the corresponding price (column C).

If you could point me into the right direction, it would be appreciated very much.

```
import json
import boto3 
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
result = {}
intent=""
Carname=""
Color=""
table = dynamodb.Table('mytable')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    intent=(event['currentIntent']['name'])
    #print('the intent is : ',intent)
    Carname=(event['currentIntent']['slots']['Carname_slot'])
    #print('carname is : ',Carname)
    if intent=='Carname_intent':
        colorenquiry(Carname)
        return result
        
# This function should figure out which colors are available for the carname.


def colorenquiry(Carname):
    response = table.query(
    IndexName='Carname-index',
    TableName='mytable',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('Carname').eq(Carname))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @itprorh66. I edited my question and gave more detail. I hope it's more clear now. If I should elaborate, please let me know!